# What are Custom Controls? What is the basic difference between the user controls and custom controls?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Could any give me a best Custom control application with code snippet and explain me the basic difference between Custom control and user control?
Thanks in advance ,
Laxmi

Comment: Please take a look at the following articles regarding this issue: [Recommendations for Web User Controls vs. Web Custom Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa651710%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) [Overview of user controls vs. custom controls](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893667)

Comment: [Difference between User Control and Custom Control?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/367640/102112)

Comment: [What are the differences between User Controls, Server Controls & Custom Controls?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/994009/102112)

Comment: [ASP.Net Custom controls vs. user controls: Are these two the same](http://stackoverflow.com/q/673370/102112)

Comment: end even [user control vs custom control](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3750596/102112)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**User Control** is collection or grouping of WebControls. It is similar to aspx page and is used to place common markup code in a common file.

Refer [Web Forms User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28VS.71%29.aspx) to create user control, convert page to user control, consume user control, e.t.c

**Custom Control** Inherits from WebControl to achieve some extra functionality. These are classes.

Sample Custom Control

```
public class DropdownListExtended : DropdownList
{
    // My custom logic
    // ususaly an event is overriden by developers to achieve extra functionality
}
```

- **Webcontrols:-** are TextBox, Label, DropdownList, e.t.c

Hopefully your understanding are builds.

Comment: @enjoyprogramming, it will be better to consider usability instead of performance in this case.